# Adding buttons "inline-block" with image float right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add my site's logo to the left part of my header, and buttons to the right side along with a label within the same div. I've tried setting an outer div, and inner div with an inline-block statement, but for some reason it does not seem to be working. Here's the html:

```
<section class="header">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="logo float-left">
                      <div class="signup">
                    <a href="#top">
                    <img src="” alt=""/> //LOGO
                    </a>
                               </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.header {
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;

}
.header .container {
    padding: 0px;
}

.logo {
    padding-top:0px;
    float:left;
}

.signup{

      padding-top:0px;
      float:right;  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/8f3wc/)

Keep it really really simple

### html

```
<header class="global-header">

<img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="logo" />    

<div class="signup">
    <a href="#">
        Sign-up
    </a>
</div>
```

### css

```
.global-header {
    overflow: hidden; /* this should be clear-fixed instead */
}

.logo {
    display: block; /* get rid of the lame space beneith by default as well as to let it be floated */
    float:left;
}

.signup {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's keep it simple. Using HTML5? Might as well use the header tag to wrap it all together.

Give the image an ID as the logo will be unique. The signup block is a div, but is it going to be a form? Let's give it a unique ID.

HTML

```
<header>
    <img src="" alt="Logo" id="logo" />
        <div id="signup">
            <a href="#">Whatever</a>
        </div>
</header>

<div id="content">

</div>
```

The body is centered just to make it easy to visualise on a massive screen. Let's float the logo to the left. No need to wrap it in a div. The signup block is floated to the right. Finally, the div that will contain your content will clear the floats.

CSS

```
body {
  width:800px;
  margin:0 auto
}

header {
  overflow:hidden;
  height:100px;
  background:#0C6
}

/*The overflow allows for the height to be maintained for a background or whatever... */
img#logo {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  float:left
}

#signup {
  float:right
}

#content {
  clear:both
}
```